# What does Linux GKI stand for?

Tags: c, linux, nfc

What do they refer to with GKI [here](https://github.com/NXPNFCLinux/linux_libnfc-nci/blob/master/src/libnfc-nci/gki/common/gki_common.h)? What does it abbreviate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to stand for **General Kernel Interface**, not that it is much useful as itself.

For example:

> The libnfc-nci implementation uses a reliable mechanism of queues and message passing named General Kernel Interface (GKI) to easily communicate between layers and modules: Each task is isolated, owning a buffer (or inbox) where messages are queued and processed on arrival. This mechanism is used to send messages from the DH to the NFCC chip, and vice versa.

([Radio Frequency Identification: 11th International Workshop, RFIDsec 2015](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319248363))